# AWS S3 getObject decodificar

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aws, amazon-s3

Estoy utilizando S3 desde una api para almacenar y obtener archivos.
Anteriormente para obtener un archivo, le pre-asignaba una url temporal con getSignedUrl()
pero ya no quiero obtener una url, lo que quiero es manejar los datos crudos del archivo.

Codigo antes (me retorna una url):

```
 const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key })
 return await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 })
```

Código nuevo(Al parecer me retorna un array de bits):

```
const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key })
const response = await client.send(command);
return await response.Body.transformToByteArray();
```

Mostrando en consola lo que retorna el codigo nuevo
(Al parecer es un array de dos archivos que estan codificados)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero convertirlos en sus respectivos tipos de archivos para posteriormente mandarlos al cliente y mostrar el pdf en un modal para su impresion, uno es un pdf y otro es un xml

Comment: S3 no recodifica nada. Simplemente no estás usando correctamente las funciones de AWS. `GetObjectCommand` no te devuelve un archivo sino un objeto que, entre otras cosas, contiene el archivo pedido. El contenido del archivo se encuentra en `command.Body`